# Getting polygon with max attribute within polygons with same geometry using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, geodataframe, maximum

I have a GeoDataframe containing the spatially joined result of a square grid map and flood hazard data. However, there are instances of rows with the same `"geometry"` but differing `"flood_score"` data (because of the spatial join intersection). How do I keep only the max `"flood_score"` data for each unique `"geometry"`?

[image]

I've tried the code below:

```py
test = mrkna_grid.dissolve(by='flood_score', aggfunc='max')
```

However, it only returns 4 rows (as opposed to thousands) and grouped it by the `"flood_score"`.

[image]

Essentially, I want to do this, but it doesn't work with `"geometry"`:

```py
df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby(['geometry'])['flood_score'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused by what column it is exactly you're wanting to group the dataframe by. Can you give an example of your desired output? You have specifically asked the dataframe to be grouped by flood score

Comment: @JoeBe I want to group them by the `geometry`, getting only the maximum `flood_score`. When I spatially joined the two maps, it resulted in duplicate `geometry` data with different `flood_score` values. For example, there are two rows with `geometry`  x, but with different `flood_score` data because they both intersected. I only want one instance of `geometry` x that has the maximum of the `flood_score` data.

Comment: @Taras The row count has been decreased to the same amount before the spatial join, indicating that the duplicates have been removed. If the function `drop_duplicates` drops rows from a top-down order based on the sorted dataframe, then this should be correct. You can post this as an answer and I'll mark it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume there is polygon layer (a shapefile) with the following attribute table, see image below

[image: input]

With this code I am loading this shapefile into a GeoDataFrame

```py
import geopandas as gpd

file = "P:/Test/qgis_test/test_for_geopandas.shp"

gdf = gpd.read_file(file)
print(gdf)
```

The GeoDataFrame itself

```
    fid  ...                                           geometry
0   6.0  ...  POLYGON ((233499.352 5752838.208, 559980.331 5...
1   7.0  ...  POLYGON ((233499.352 5752838.208, 559980.331 5...
2   8.0  ...  POLYGON ((233499.352 5752838.208, 559980.331 5...
3   9.0  ...  POLYGON ((978501.160 5695530.377, 1164317.462 ...
4  10.0  ...  POLYGON ((978501.160 5695530.377, 1164317.462 ...
5  11.0  ...  POLYGON ((978501.160 5695530.377, 1164317.462 ...
6  12.0  ...  POLYGON ((978501.160 5695530.377, 1164317.462 ...
7  13.0  ...  POLYGON ((978501.160 5695530.377, 1164317.462 ...
8  14.0  ...  POLYGON ((978501.160 5695530.377, 1164317.462 ...
9  15.0  ...  POLYGON ((485306.490 4940108.963, 681542.397 5...

[10 rows x 4 columns]
```

With the following code, it is possible to *keep only the max `"flood_score"` data for each unique `geometry`*.

```
gdf_ = gdf.sort_values('flood_scor', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['geometry'])
print(gdf_)
```

The output GeoDataFrame will look like:

```
    fid  ...                                           geometry
8  14.0  ...  POLYGON ((978501.160 5695530.377, 1164317.462 ...
1   7.0  ...  POLYGON ((233499.352 5752838.208, 559980.331 5...
9  15.0  ...  POLYGON ((485306.490 4940108.963, 681542.397 5...

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the geometries are identical, you dont need to dissolve, just drop the duplicates:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r'C:\GIS\data\tempdata\my.shp')
df['wkt'] = df.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.to_wkt()) #Create a wkt string column

df = df.sort_values(by='flood_source') #Sort by flood_source
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['wkt'], keep='last') #Drop duplicate wkt keep last/largest flood source value

df.to_file(r'C:\GIS\data\tempdata\my_nodups.shp') #Save
```